# Interval at time of emission and observation between two photons

Tags: cosmology, photons, time-dilation, redshift

In deriving how scale factor is related to redshift $1 + z = \frac{1}{a(t_e)}$, we started by saying the first light wave obeys:

$c\int^{t_o}_{t_e}\frac{dt}{a(t)} = r$, where r is comoving distance.

Then we say, the next light wave would be emitted at $t_e + \lambda_e /c$, and arrive at time $t_o+\lambda_o/c$,

$c\int^{t_o+\lambda_o/c}_{t_e+\lambda_e/c}\frac{dt}{a(t)} = r$.

Setting the two equal to each other, making use of $z = \frac{\lambda_o - \lambda_e}{\lambda_e}$and then we'll get to the final result.

But my question is why should the second wave -- if thinking about light as photons, why would the time a 2nd photon was emitted related to its wavelength $\lambda_e$? Wouldn't a galaxy randomly emit a lot of photons at all times? And if a 2nd photon is emitted at a random time interval later, say at $t_e + t_{e_{delay}}$, how should the boundaries of the second integral be modified?

Comment: Yes, but in your derivation you are considering the same wave (so the same photon) with a precise wavelength.  Note that this type of redshift is only due to space expansion. For 2nd photon you apply the same formula because the derivation still the same.

Comment: I don't know the exact reasons, but considering a galaxy as a monochromatic wave source, you can detect signals at discrete time moments $$t_n=t_0+nT=t_0+\frac nf=t_0+\frac {n\lambda}{c}$$

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas, yes that's exactly it, but I want to know why? Do you have a source for this? From a book or website? What's the context around it. Thanks!

Comment: Because next wave crest will arrive at least after period $T=1/f$, it's inherent wave property.

Comment: For building your intuition, - try imaging standing in the sea beach in water. When some sea wave bumps into you and you have "absorbed the wave hit",- you have to wait for a next wave to come, right? This waiting time is exactly a period at which source generates waves and is inversely proportional to frequency.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas, lol, but you said "I don't know the exact reasons". I understand the intuition for mechanical wave such as water wave, but photons are different. They're electrons transiting between energy levels, why would the time the next electron transition be dependent on the wavelength of the previous photon?

Comment: All oscillations has period/frequency independent of their nature.

Comment: As for about your replica "_but you said_", I'll respond with Einstein quote: **"Imagination is more important than knowledge. For knowledge is limited, whereas imagination embraces the entire world, stimulating progress, giving birth to evolution."**.

Comment: "...why would the time the next electron transition be dependent on the wavelength of the previous photon?" Got the same issue, I guess: if the frequency of the photon equates its energy, how can the shift in wavelength not only be virtual to the receiver? Once the photon is emitted, the Doppler effect depends on movements that are independent from the photon's energy at time of emittance. Is there a kinetic inverse gravitational red shift (non Doppler!) i.e. does  the impulse of the photon depend on the direction of the source at time of emittance?? In this moment I do believe so.